# Python Sympy solver got error while solving triangle equation

Tags: python, sympy

> Python 3.8.2
>
> sympy 1.5.1

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol,sin,cos,simplify
x = Symbol('x')
solve( sin(x)**5 - cos(x)**5 , x)
```

got error

```
PolynomialError: generator must be a Symbol
```

But then reduce the order 5 to 4 , its ok

```
solve( sin(x)**4 - cos(x)**4 , x)

[-3*pi/4, -pi/4, pi/4, 3*pi/4]
```

Comment: This is a bug in sympy: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/19113

Comment: Is there any solution to the bug now?

Comment: Fixed in Sympy 1.6